# Concatenate and shorten days in a week in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, oracle11g

I have Timings columns as

```
M 8:00 AM - 5:00 PM | Tu 8:00 AM - 5:00 PM | W 8:00 AM - 5:00 PM | Th 8:00 AM - 5:00 PM | F 8:00 AM - 5:00 PM
```

Would like to generate it as

```
M-F 8:00 AM - 5:00 PM
```

Sometimes the timings might change as

```
M 9:00 am - 9:00 pm | Tu 9:00 am - 9:00 pm | W 9:00 am - 9:00 pm | Th 9:00 am - 9:00 pm | F 9:00 am - 9:00 pm | Sa 9:00 am - 9:00 pm | Su 10:00 am - 6:00 pm
```

In this case I have to generate as

```
M-Sa 9:00 am - 9:00 pm | Su 10:00 am - 6:00 pm
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this step-by-step example. Follow comments written within the code.

Take it as a *guide* to what you might do as this approach won't work properly if there were different time spans somewhere "in the middle" (for example, for Thursday). Groups would still be OK, but days (named in shortened version) would be kind of wrong as you'd get e.g. `M-Su 9:00 am - 9:00 pm | Th 9:00 am - 4:00 pm`. If that doesn't bother you, fine.

```
SQL> with
  2  test (id, col) as
  3    (
  4     select 1, 'M 8:00 AM - 5:00 PM | Tu 8:00 AM - 5:00 PM | W 8:00 AM - 5:00 PM | Th 8:00 AM - 5:00 PM | F 8:00 AM - 5:00 PM' from dual union all
  5     select 2, 'M 9:00 am - 9:00 pm | Tu 9:00 am - 9:00 pm | W 9:00 am - 9:00 pm | Th 9:00 am - 9:00 pm | F 9:00 am - 9:00 pm | Sa 9:00 am - 9:00 pm | Su 10:00 am - 6:00 pm' from dual
  6    ),
  7  temp as
  8    -- split column to rows
  9    (select id,
 10            column_value rn,
 11            trim(regexp_substr(upper(col), '[^|]+', 1, column_value)) val
 12     from test join table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
 13                                        connect by level <= regexp_count(col, '\|') + 1
 14                                       ) as sys.odcinumberlist)) on 1 = 1
 15    ),
 16  extr as
 17    -- extract day and time span into separate columns (for aggregating purposes)
 18    (
 19     select id,
 20            rn,
 21            substr(val, 1, instr(val, ' ')) c_day,
 22            substr(val, instr(val, ' ') + 1) c_period
 23     from temp
 24    ),
 25  agg1 as
 26    (-- group values from the previous step
 27     select id,
 28            listagg(trim(c_day), ', ') within group (order by rn) days,
 29            c_period
 30     from extr
 31     group by id, c_period
 32    )
 33    -- the final result
 34  select id,
 35         listagg
 36           (initcap(regexp_substr(days, '^\w+') ||'-'|| regexp_substr(days, '\w+$')) || ' ' || lower(c_period), ' | ')
 37            within group (order by id)
 38            val
 39  from agg1
 40  group by id
 41  order by id;

 ID VAL
--- --------------------------------------------------
  1 M-F 8:00 am - 5:00 pm
  2 M-Sa 9:00 am - 9:00 pm | Su-Su 10:00 am - 6:00 pm

SQL>
```

---

Alternatively, instead of shortening it that much, you could name all days that share the same time span, which would return the correct result regardless of which day(s) have a different time span. For example:

```
 <... snip, as previous lines are not modified ...>
 25  agg1 as
 26    (-- group values from the previous step
 27     select id,
 28            listagg(trim(initcap(c_day)), ', ') within group (order by rn) ||' ' || upper(c_period) val
 29     from extr
 30     group by id, c_period
 31    )
 32    -- the final result
 33  select id,
 34         listagg (val, ' | ') within group (order by id) val
 35  from agg1
 36  group by id
 37  order by id;

 ID VAL
--- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  1 M, Tu, W, Th, F 8:00 AM - 5:00 PM
  2 M, Tu, W, F, Sa 9:00 AM - 9:00 PM | Su 10:00 AM - 6:00 PM | Th 9:00 AM - 4:00 PM

SQL>
```

Comment: Thank you, the second one helped a lot.